# Why does my strategy use data from the second entry signal instead of the first entry signal if the take profit hasn't been met yet?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api

I created a simple ema crossover strategy with a take profit at 1.5 times the ATR.

For some reason, if my first take profit is not met before a another entry signal (crossover) occurs, the strategy will move my take profit to 1.5 times the ATR from the second entry signal instead of keeping it at 1.5 times the ATR from the first entry signal.

Does anyone have a fix for this?
Below is my code and a picture explaining the issue:

[image: Image of issue (https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYgZl.png)]

```
//@version=5
strategy("EMA Bullish Cross with 2 TP Levels", overlay=true)
 
// Input variables
emaFastLength = input.int(10, "EMA Fast Length")
emaSlowLength = input.int(20, "EMA Slow Length")
atrLength = input.int(5, "ATR Length")
tpMultiplier = input.float(1.5, "Take Profit 1 Multiplier")
 
// Calculate EMA and ATR
emaFast = ta.ema(close, emaFastLength)
emaSlow = ta.ema(close, emaSlowLength)
atr = ta.atr(atrLength)
var float persistantATR = na
 
// Determine if there's a bullish EMA cross
Cross = ta.cross(emaFast, emaSlow)
 
// Enter long trade if there's a bullish EMA cross
if (Cross) 
    persistantATR := atr
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, qty = 100 )
 
    entry_price = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)
    strategy.exit("Take Profit", "Buy", qty_percent = 100, limit= entry_price + (persistantATR *           tpMultiplier))
 
// debugging
plot(atr, title = "atr")
plot(persistantATR, title = "persistantATR")
```

I removed the stop loss condition, just for debugging. I also tried testing the strategy on different time frames.

Answer (score 0):

With your 'if (Cross)' condition, it will execute the strategy.entry and the strategy.exit each time a cross occurs.
In your example:
On the first cross, the strategy.entry is done and a strategy.exit is placed (with your limit= entry_price + (persistantATR*tpMultiplier).
On the second cross, the strategy.entry is read but not executed as you have already an entry with the same name which is on. But the strategy.exit is executed, changing your limit to the actual value.

To prevent this, you can use strategy.opentrades and test if no trade is already on before entering your condition block :
NB : strategy.opentrades gives you the number of trades opened (in your case it will be 0 or 1)

```
//@version=5
strategy("EMA Bullish Cross with 2 TP Levels", overlay=true)
 
// Input variables
emaFastLength = input.int(10, "EMA Fast Length")
emaSlowLength = input.int(20, "EMA Slow Length")
atrLength = input.int(5, "ATR Length")
tpMultiplier = input.float(1.5, "Take Profit 1 Multiplier")
 
// Calculate EMA and ATR
emaFast = ta.ema(close, emaFastLength)
emaSlow = ta.ema(close, emaSlowLength)
atr = ta.atr(atrLength)
var float persistantATR = na
 
// Determine if there's a bullish EMA cross
Cross = ta.cross(emaFast, emaSlow)
 
// Enter long trade if there's a bullish EMA cross
if (Cross) and strategy.opentrades == 0
    persistantATR := atr
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, qty = 100 )
 
    entry_price = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)
    strategy.exit("Take Profit", "Buy", qty_percent = 100, limit= entry_price + (persistantATR *           tpMultiplier))
 
// debugging
plot(atr, title = "atr")
plot(persistantATR, title = "persistantATR")
```